# screen and serial UART connection gibberish

Tags: pi-3b+, serial, ubuntu, uart, macos

I'm connecting my iMac (10.14.16) to my RPi 3b+ (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS ubuntu ttyS0, `uname -a` = `Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-1067-raspi2 #71-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 10 01:36:10 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`) to get power and console access. The USB device I'm using is [this one here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D6LLX19), and I have the SILABS driver com.silabs.driver.CP210xVCPDriver (5.3.5) installed. I'm using Mac's `screen` (4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06)). The command I'm using to connect is `/usr/bin/screen /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 11520`. Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't. When it does work, I see the following output in my iTerm console on the Mac.

```
[   41.451258] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   41.500478] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm64.
[   41.539203] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <ubuntu>.
[   42.138182] systemd[1]: Configuration file /etc/systemd/system/upswift.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
[   42.297596] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[   42.317333] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   42.349367] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   42.368882] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[   42.389396] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   42.408458] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   42.489781] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   42.564316] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
�6��������2l�|�6�&�>~ξ�6�2>6��2��L��L�B�`�f������l���2��|��lL�p|l��p�l���������&�0���>�2�&ƾB�6�����������Bf���f�0&�>�l������>�&Μ>6���|&�B��2�6���~��|�6�2�`l�pB�`�6���Ǝ���>Lf�p��fΜr&���p��&Μ�2����&�p`&��6�~�2��rf��L>�6�Μ�p��f��p��6Μrf����6l�r�|06���p��Ό�~��p`6������p>��ll|6ƾ��r�[   46.322706] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   47.342726] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS ubuntu ttyS0

ubuntu login:
```

My question is, why is the gibberish mixed in the middle of legible output? Or, what is causing the gibberish when screen seems to be doing a fine job otherwise? Is there a `.screenrc` option I can set? Is that gibberish supposed to be colored output, and screen isn't interpreting it? Also, I remember reading discussion about cheap, knockoff USB connectors on Amazon not working as expected with Prolific or SILABS drivers, but I can't recall the source---so maybe this is an issue?

Comment: Are you using the same character encoding? I don't know how to set it in screen but using UTF-8 I believe will fix the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762480/how-to-make-gnu-screen-recognize-utf-8-characters this might help